# Timer Using Alarm Manager on Android (React Native)

Tags: java, react-native

I'm trying to create a timer that can run even when the app is closed. I've been trying to use react-native-background-timer which works great, but we need the timer to be working even if the app is closed.

I've been trying to use CountDownTimer, but I found out that when it's closed, the timer will be stopped. Can I resolve this problem using AlarmManager instead? Also, I need to update notification every minute (to show the remaining time, just like in Timer native android app) but I can't invoke the callback more than once (i need to get remaining milliseconds). What's the best approach for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can resolve this issue by using AlarmManager.

And for the notification, you will need to create local notification, assigning Notification ID and inside timer call createNotification function which will update notification on interval by giving it same ID

I hope this could help you